# Want to show div on last option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a drop down with specific id and have a div with specific id as well , what i need is to show that div when last option of that drop down is selected or the selected value of that option is "custom-size" , and i am trying to do in this way and its not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('#pa_size-stitch').change(function(){
    $('#pa_size-stitch').find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($('#pa_size-stitch').attr("value")!=="custom-size"){


 $("#tm-extra-product-options").hide();
        }

        else{
            $("#tm-extra-product-options").show();
        }
    });
}).change();});
```

and its not working , any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#pa_size-stitch').change(function(evt) {
        if( $(this).val() == "custom-size" ){
            $("#tm-extra-product-options").show();
        } else {
            $("#tm-extra-product-options").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks , Working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('#pa_size-stitch').change(function() {
    var isShown = this.value == 'custom-size' ||
                  (this.selectedIndex + 1) == this.options.length;

    $("#tm-extra-product-options").toggle(isShown);
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edjdgq8v/1/)

Comment: Would you please check here : http://bazar.innovativeartz.com/product/1-kg/

Comment: Good optimization :), improved my coding style

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#pa_size-stitch', function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#pa_size-stitch :selected').val();

    if(selectedVal == $('#pa_size-stitch option:last()').val() || selectedVal == "custom-size") $("#tm-extra-product-options").hide();

    else $("#tm-extra-product-options").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#pa_size-stitch').change(function() {
  
  $('option:selected', this).text() == "custom-size" || $("option:last",this).is(":selected") ? $("#tm-extra-product-options").hide() : $("#tm-extra-product-options").show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_size-stitch">
  <option>l</option>
  <option>custom-size</option>
  <option>l</option>
</select>

<div id="tm-extra-product-options">asdad</div>
```

1. Use `$('option:selected', this).text() == "custom-size"`  to check for same text.
2. `$("option:last",this).is(":selected")` to check for last child